# Access @functions from another file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, devextreme

I am using **.NET Core 3.1**. I have the following piece of code in `Index.cshtml` file:

```
@functions
{
    public DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc.Builders.FileUploaderBuilder GetFileUploader(int type, bool multi)
    {
        string buttonText = multi ? "test1" : "test2";
        string labelText = multi ? "abc1" : "abc2";

        return Html.DevExtreme().FileUploader()
            .SelectButtonText(buttonText)
            .LabelText(labelText)
            .Multiple(multi)
            .Accept(Constants.ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS_HTML[type]);
    }
}
```

I want to use this function in `Details.cshtml` as well. How can I do this?

Comment: Well, refactor the method to some internal static class with helper methods? :) It's a good tone to separate UI and logic (even if the logic is about UI building)

Comment: How can I use `Html.DevExtreme().FileUploader()...` outside of `.cshtml` file?

Comment: You can make it another method parameter (so that it becomes `GetFileUploader(int, bool, Html)`; also, I've just thought of another option - you can try to make method static, and access in another page using type qualification (though, it raises the question of how the page class is named)

Comment: Make this an HtmlHelper extension or a Tag Helper.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Can you provide an example for my case?